# I'm trying to manually build an intermediary table for a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I need to generate a table for a many-many look up (I'm thinking it should be a HABTM because of the simple nature of the lookup.  One plant can have one or many months where it blooms, and all months will have many plants blooming in them.

My current plant data has a "flower_time" column with comma separated abbreviations.  For every plant, I iterate through I need to add a new row in the months_plants table.

**`month_plant.rb`**

```
class CreateMonthPlants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :month_plants, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :month_id, index: true
      t.integer :plant_id, index: true
    end
  end

  def drop
    drop_table :month_id
  end
end
```

**`plant.rb`**

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :detail
  has_and_belongs_to_many :months
end
```

**`month.rb`**

```
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and belongs_to_many :plants
end
```

**`month_plant.rb`**

```
class MonthPlant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :month
  belongs_to :plant
end
```

**`XXX_controller`**

```
  def common
    c = 0
    @plants = Plant
      .order(:id)
    @plants.each do | p|
      if p.flower_time == "Not of Interest"
       bloom = Month_plant.create(plant_id: p.id, "month_id = 13")
        c += 1
      end 
      if p.flower_time == "Unknown"
       bloom = Month_plant.create(:plant_id => p.id, "month_id = 14")
        c += 1
      end 
      if p.flower_time != "Not of Interest" and p.flower_time != "Unknown" 
        a = p.flower_time.split ','
        a.each do | b |
          m = case (b)
            when 'Jan' then 1
            when 'Feb' then 2
            when 'Mar' then 3
            when 'Apr' then 4
            when 'May' then 5
            when 'Jun' then 6
            when 'Jul' then 7
            when 'Aug' then 8
            when 'Sep' then 9
            when 'Oct' then 10
            when 'Nov' then 11
            when 'Dec' then 12
          end
          bloom = Month_plant.create(:plant_id => p.id, 'month_id = ?", m)
          c += 1
        end 
      end 
      @cc = c
   end
end
```

I know the above code isn't pretty, but the logic worked when I outputted to screen.  When I try to output to the database I get the following error:
*Unable to autoload constant Month_plant, expected c:/Sites/sg2017/app/models/month_plant.rb to define it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Month_plant` should be replaced by `MonthPlant`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14434888)

Comment: He already set up correct relationships and said that the logic worked, but he got error with naming of model, so he just needs to fix it. Why doesn't it an answer?

Comment: It's alright, you detected the exact issue, but how `MonthPlant` this name will work? any explanation...

Comment: @Thanh I agree with you - that IS the answer.  After fixing a couple of other minor issues, it worked like a charm.